# Laravel Routing - different routes to same controller for RESTful API

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am building a RESTful controller in Laravel and have a project which contains many jobs. So to list the projects we can do GET /projects. To list a specific project we can do `GET /projects/{id}` and this will also list all the jobs associated with this project. But if the user wants to View/Add/Edit or delete a specific job is it best practice to route it like

(a) `GET /projects/{id}/jobs/{id}`

or

(b) `GET /jobs/{id}`

or

(c) BOTH (route to the same controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jobs always belong to a project then you should use:

```
GET /projects/{id}/jobs/{id}
```

but if you can have a job that is not associated to a project, then you should use:

```
GET /jobs/{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Organize your webpages in a logical structure, if *jobs* can belong to more than one project I would choose option (b), otherwise option (a).